# Transient response of a driven damped oscillator to system parameter change

Tags: classical-mechanics, resonance

Imagine a damped driven mass spring system with a time-dependent damping coefficient
\begin{equation}
m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + b(t)\frac{dx}{dt} + kx = F_0 cos(wt)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
b(t) =
    \begin{cases}
      b_1 & t< t_0\\
      b_2 & t\geq t_0
    \end{cases} 
\end{equation}

I am trying to understand how the system would respond to the change in damping coefficient at $t = t_0$. Can we talk about a transient response in that case?

The concept of transient response is often explained with respect to initial conditions of a system and its input signal. I never saw an example where the system's response to a change in internal parameter is investigated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Can we talk about a transient response in that case?*
Yes, as in effect you are considering a new system with initial conditions set at $t=t_0$.

Just think about what would happen if you set $b_2=0$.
Then you would expect the system to undergo undamped simple harmonic motion with the initial conditions set at $t=t_0$.

Comment: I see. Then, the transient response will be determined by the new system's parameters.